# How do I prove the following inequality for the probability using Markov?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

I have the following problem:

> Given a random variable $Y$ such that $\Bbb{E}(Y^2)<\infty$. I want to show that $$\Bbb{P}(Y>a)\leq \frac{\Bbb{E}(Y^2)}{a^2}$$ for $a\neq 0$.

So my idea was to use the Markov inequality as follows:

> Since $\Bbb{E}(Y^2)<\infty$ we know that $Y\in L^2(\Bbb{P})\Rightarrow Y\in L^1(\Bbb{P})$. Then let us consider the following cases:
>
> 1. $a>0$. Then $$\Bbb{P}(Y>a)\leq \Bbb{P}(Y\geq a)\leq \Bbb{P}(|Y|\geq a)=\Bbb{P}(Y^2\geq a^2)\stackrel{Markov}{\leq}\frac{\Bbb{E}(Y^2)}{a^2}$$

Is this correct so far?

now I thought about the case when $a<0$. But somehow I don't think I can proceed similarly as above do I?

Comment: Your first equation should be $E[Y^2]$ on the right, not $P[Y^2]$.  This inequality is only true for $a>0$.  You can find counter-examples otherwise (or just take $a\rightarrow-\infty$ for a counter-example).

Comment: So you mean with $[]$ brackets instead of $()$?

Ah but my prove is valid for $a>0$ or is there a mistake?

Comment: Ah sorry I saw where you mean it. I corrected it. Now everything should be correct right, also my prove I hope.

Comment: Yes your proof for $a>0$ looks good.